# CodeIgniter - How to print an array in the view?

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

sorry if the questions seams stupid but I have created an array in my controller and I pass it to the view with the `$data[]` array.
And I don't get it right to print the array with a for loop.
Can you please help me?

```
$measurearray = array(
    'nr' => $answerNr,
    'responsible' => $responsible,
    'creationdate' => $InvDate2,
    'activity' => $reason
);
$arr[$i] = $measurearray;
$data["failedMeasures_nr"] = $arr;
```

Output :

```
Array ( 
  [50] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
      [nr] => 5d 
      [responsible] => werner 
      [creationdate] => asdfgdf 
      [activity] => appointed. 
    ) 
  ) 
  [73] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
      [nr] => 9g 
      [responsible] => 42887 
      [creationdate] => Zuzana 
      [activity] => r the training. 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This is what happens when I `print_r()` it in the view.

My target is to print every single element for itself!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach ( $failedMeasures_nr[0] as $key => $val ) {
   echo $key . ' is ' . $val; 
}
```

With a `foreach` you can print separately the array elements

Please note that if you want to print more than the first index ( the 0 in my example ) you should use another `foreach`, resulting in something like this:

```
foreach ( $failedMeasures_nr as $new_arr ) {
    foreach ( $new_arr as $key => $val ) {
       echo $key . ' is ' . $val; 
    }
}
```

this way you will print the whole array separately

Answer (score 0):

```
// controller page try this,
$data[$i]["failedMeasures_nr"] =array('nr' => $answerNr,
                                  'responsible' => $responsible,
                                  'creationdate' => $InvDate2,
                                  'activity' => $reason);
$this->load->view('view_page',$data);

In View Page try this code,

for($i =0 ; $i <count($data);$i++){
   foreach ($data[$i] as $key => $value) {
       echo "$value";
       echo "<br>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach method to print each value.

```
<?php 
             foreach ($failedMeasures_nr as $print):

                            echo $print['nr'];
                            echo $print['responsible'];
                            echo $print['creationdate']; 
                            echo $print['activity'];

             endforeach; 
?>
```